# Etiquette query on help/sourcecode

Tags: discussion

I asked a few questions on SO and was able to learn sufficient amounts of information to get a project working. Now that I've written it, I wanted to release my source to any interested parties under some form of attribution license.

(I picked one from CC but can't recall the full code off the top of my head.)
Seeing how SO is a Q/A site, it seemeth inappropriate to slap it up over there. As small of a program as this is, though, it seems a bit odd to throw it on to Sourceforge.

I was wondering what people thought on the matter. Is there a good place to pop something like this up for people to play with?

{It's a Python 2.6* ANOVA (2-way) calculator in vanilla Python, which means no libraries need be added. (*it's fairly basic, but I haven't checked which versions it works in.) It generates the p-value and can perform linear contrasts, and can generate ranking by either of the factors so Friedman's non-parametric ANOVA by ranks can also be performed.

I lost the update where I got had it assisting in generating linear contrasts, so I might also have lost some of the convenience functions for manual input as well. I think it's better as an example of API design than program design, but it does work. }

Comment: First I wanted to close this as `Off-Topic`, but the answer is `Not on SO`.

Comment: Asking about what's appropriate on Stack Overflow is not on-topic for its meta site? Interesting.

Comment: That's why I said `First I wanted`, because your question sounded to me like `Where can I host my code?`, but then I realized that it is partly on-topic and the answer is a simple `not here`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't designed to store code: it's a question-and-answer site. That being said, you can always put your code on a site like [GitHub](https://github.com/) and then link to it from [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434591/the-nate).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I might just slap it up there, then. (I realize that SO focuses on Q/A, hence I asked.)